# No value accessor for form control with name 'startTime' and 'endTime'

Tags: angular, time, bootstrap-4, timepicker

app.module have

```js
import { TimepickerModule, TimepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/timepicker';
import { getTimepickerConfig  } from './TimepickerConfig';

imports: [
  BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
  TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
],
providers: [
 { provide: TimepickerConfig, useFactory: getTimepickerConfig }
]
```

HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="addProjectForm">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Start Time</label>
            <timepicker formControlName="startTime" ></timepicker>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>End Time</label>
            <timepicker formControlName="endTime" ></timepicker>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

ts

```js
this.addProjectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   startTime:[Date, [Validators.required]],
   endTime:["", [Validators.required]]
});

this.startTime = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `FormsModule` and ReactiveFormsModule`

```js
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TimepickerModule, TimepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/timepicker';
import { getTimepickerConfig  } from './TimepickerConfig';

imports: [
  BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
  TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
],
```

Generally the error `No value accessor for form control ...`  means the component which is used with the reactive form directive (eg `formControlName`, `formControl`) doesn't know how to handle the reactive form directive.